# How do I prove a record related lemma?

Tags: coq, beginner, forward-proof, proof-techniques

I'm new to coq. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Consider the following definition:

```ml
Record person:= mk_person { p_name : t1; p_age : t2}.
```

How to prove the following lemma?

```ml
Lemma person_lemma : forall (p:person)(name:t1)(age:t2), 
    p_name p = name ->
    p_age  p = age  ->
    p ={|p_name := name; p_age := age|}.
```

Comment: Welcome to PASE! It would be nice if you can share your own effort and what problems you have encountered. You have given examples using some types like `t1`, `t2` which are not defined in your question. It is easier to get people to help you if you provide these background information.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this open, not just because this is a brand new user, but also because an answer was already given (the question does not "need details for clarity", which was the currently proposed close reason).

Comment: @NikeDattani It still needs detail. Where exactly is the difficulty? Where is the OP stuck? We need to know that in order to give helpful answers.

Comment: @Trebor the question got an answer.

Comment: @NikeDattani I'm not voting because my decisions would be final. But having an answer doesn't really affect the close reasons.

Comment: @Trebor comments are not for extended discussions. If you disagree with my vote, we can discuss in chat. I've avoided responding to you in detail here for that reason.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that a records is syntactic sugar for an inductive with one constructor. Your record is mostly equivalent to:

```ml
Inductive person:= mk_person: forall(p_name : t1)(p_age : t2), person.
```

and the projection functions:

```ml
Definition p_name (p:person) := let '(mk_person name _) := p in name.
Definition p_age (p:person) := let '(mk_person _ age) := p in age.
```

One difference is that this way you don't have the `{| ... |} notation, so the lemma would be rephrased  like this:

```ml
Lemma person_lemma : forall (p:person)(name:t1)(age:t2), 
    p_name p = name ->
    p_age  p = age  ->
    p = mk_person name age.
```

If you know to prove this lemma, then the same script should work for the record:

```ml
  intros p name age H H0. 
  destruct p.
  now subst.
```